# Call a TVF in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table-valued function in SQL Server and I want call this from EF.

SQL Server code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_SearchTitle(@q AS NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN
   (SELECT * FROM Advertise
    WHERE FREETEXT([Title], @q));
```

In SQL Server everything is ok but not in Entity Framework.

I create an entity with database-first method and import table-valued function. Now I want use this function like this:

```
using (var context = new testEntities())
{
   var res = context.fn_SearchTitle("iphone");

   foreach (var result in res)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(result.Title);
   }
}
```

This code throws this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Details:
The full-text query parameter for Fulltext Query String is not valid.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The full-text query parameter for Fulltext Query String is not valid.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: There should be inner exception with message in your exception. Could you post it?

Comment: thank you for your comment. the details of exception added to post.

Comment: After 4 years the problem is still there. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the length of the string.
You have 2 options:

1. Modify your Function. The parameter `@q` must be `varchar(MAX)`. Then
   You must use another var `NVARCHAR(50)` to cast this one. Your function must look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_SearchTitle(@q AS NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS @auxTable TABLE (AdvertiseID int, Title nvarchar(50))
BEGIN
   DECLARE @auxQ varchar(150) = Convert(varchar(150), @q)
       INSERT INTO @auxTable 
       SELECT AdvertiseID,Title FROM Advertise
       WHERE FREETEXT([Title], @auxQ);
   RETURN
END
```

2- Modify your EF function:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<YourType>("[YourEntities].[fn_SearchTitle]('" + q +"')");
```